# How to position CAShapeLayer in a UIView

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, calayer, cgpath

I saw many answers on Stack overflow, but none helped me. 
I created a DrawView where it's possible to draw. I created an instance of `UIBezierPath` for drawing. 
I want to transfer my drawing on a little view (the red one on the image). That's what I did:

```
// This function is called when the user has finished to draw.

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    //The CAShapeLayer has the same path of the drawing (currentPath is the instance of UIBezierPath).
    shapeLayer.path = currentPath?.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10.0

    //drawingView is the red view where I want to see my drawing in the center. This line of code doesn't work like I expect because the drawing doesn't appear in the center of the view.
    shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: drawingView.frame.midX, y: drawingView.frame.midY)

    //I add the shapeLayer to the drawingView.
    drawingView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

Here is an image of the app:

[image]

Any hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: drawingView.frame.midX, y: drawingView.frame.midY)
```

Everywhere you are saying `drawingView.frame`, say `drawingView.bounds` instead.

(Actually you should be saying `drawingView.layer.bounds`, not simply `drawingView.bounds`, but it happens that they are the same thing.)

However, there's also a second problem, which is that your shape layer has no size. Therefore its `position` is the same as its top left corner. For this reason you would be much better off centering it in its superlayer just by saying

```
shapeLayer.frame = drawingView.layer.bounds
```

You will then have the shape layer exactly occupying the drawing view. (You will be able to see that clearly if you give the shape layer a background color.) Now your problem will be that you want to make sure the drawing path itself is centered *in* the shape layer, but that is a different exercise.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work, the shape appears near to the initial drawing.

Comment: Because the path itself is not centered in the shape layer. Give the shape layer a background color and a size (right now it has zero size); you will see it is now centered properly.

Comment: Thank you! but I don't know how to center the path to its layer, I saw on internet but nothing helped me

Comment: Well, you have not shown anything about how the path itself is generated, so I cannot help further. Do what I said and you will see that the shape layer is now occupying the red drawing view exactly, and that is what you asked for!

Comment: Thanks Matt, this is the question for the new question about the path that is not centered. stackoverflow.com/questions/59938161/how-to-center-the-cashapelayer-path-in-the-shape-layer?noredirect=1#comment105998125_59938161

Comment: Yes but you still are saying nothing about `currentPath.cgPath`. The top left of the coordinate system in which that `cgPath` was created is going to be the top left of the shape layer when you set it into the shape layer. If that isn't what you want, it is up to you to adjust the path's position. But no one can help because you have said _nothing_ about the workings of the view into which the user "draws" the path originally.

Comment: Okay, I see what you need to do! You need to take the `boundingBoxOfPath` and go from there

Comment: Thanks! But I don't know how to use boundingBoxOfPath, because it is a get-only property.

Comment: Yes but the point is that you get it, now you know where the drawing actually is. Now you shift the drawing within the shape layer so that it is centered in the shape layer.