# How to center the CAShapeLayer path in the shape layer

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, calayer, cgpath

I created a DrawView where it's possible to draw. I created an instance of UIBezierPath for drawing.

```
// This function is called when the user has finished drawing.
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        //The CAShapeLayer has the same path of the drawing (currentPath is the instance of UIBezierPath).
        shapeLayer.path = currentPath?.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10.0

        //Here I set the shapeLayer on the drawingView (the blue one that you can see in the image)
        drawingView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: drawingView.layer.bounds.midX, y: drawingView.layer.bounds.midY)
        shapeLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        shapeLayer.frame = drawingView.layer.bounds
}
```

The problem is that the path (e.g number 3 in the image) is not centered on its shapeLayer.

```
shapeLayer.path?.boundingBoxOfPath = (289.5, 349.5, 525.0, 129.0)

shapeLayer.frame = (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 200.0)

shapeLayer.position = (100.0, 100.0)

drawingView.frame = (0.0, 912.0, 200.0, 200.0)
```

[image]

Any hint? thank you

Comment: I set the frame of the shapeLayer equal to the drawingView's frame, but it still doesn't work

Comment: The dimension of drawingView is the same of the shapeLayer

Comment: try `shapeLayer.position = drawingView.center` I'm used to draw the shape  with its center at .zero.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately if I write that code, the shapeLayer does not even appear

Comment: If you don’t post the info related to your shape we can only guess

Comment: @LeoDabus I already told him that, this is just a repeat of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937082/how-to-position-cashapelayer-in-a-uiview/59937392

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the drawing view and just think about how to center a path in a shape layer of known size. Here's a deliberate failure:

```
    let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50))
    let lay = CAShapeLayer()
    lay.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 200, height: 200)
    lay.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    lay.path = path.cgPath
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(lay)
```

We get this:

[image]

The filled circle is not centered in the red shape layer. Okay, we know why, because we know the bezier path that created the filled circle. But let's say we *don't* know that. We can still center the shape in the shape layer, like this:

```
    let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50))
    let lay = CAShapeLayer()
    lay.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 200, height: 200)
    lay.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

    let cgpath = path.cgPath
    let box = cgpath.boundingBoxOfPath
    let xtarget = (lay.bounds.width - box.width)/2
    let ytarget = (lay.bounds.height - box.height)/2
    let xoffset = xtarget - box.minX
    let yoffset = ytarget - box.minY
    var transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: xoffset, y: yoffset)
    let cgpath2 = cgpath.copy(using: &transform)
    lay.path = cgpath2

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(lay)
```

Result:

[image]

So, given a CGPath, and given a shape layer whose final bounds are known, you can use that technique to center the path in the shape layer. And those are circumstances that apply perfectly to your use case.

Comment: Thanks Matt! You helped me a lot!!